# Are there any penalties for fighting in the same 5ft space?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, optional-rules, 3d-space

A scenario occurred in my game tonight where the wizard used mold earth to cause a scenario of my barbarian and an opponent to be trapped in a 5x5 ft space that was 15ft down.

We played it as normal, but the question came up if there'd be any penalties on the character trapped in this little arena. Would there be disadvantage? Advantage?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Both characters are squeezing

The rules describe how a character can fit into a space smaller than the 5 ft. square they normally occupy, officially listed as [Squeezing into a Smaller Space](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#SqueezingintoaSmallerSpace):

> A creature can squeeze through a space that is large enough for a creature one size smaller than it. Thus, a Large creature can squeeze through a passage that's only 5 feet wide. While squeezing through a space, a creature must spend 1 extra foot for every foot it moves there, and it has disadvantage on attack rolls and Dexterity saving throws. Attack rolls against the creature have advantage while it's in the smaller space.

It's not explicit that this would apply for squeezing two characters in one space (especially if both characters are Medium, which seem like they technically can't squeeze in the first place), but it is a clear description of penalties that happen because a character isn't able to occupy their normal space. While the two creatures are fighting each other advantage and disadvantage would cancel out for attack rolls, but they would both be very vulnerable to any other creatures and if either can force single-target DEX saves instead of attacking that would give them an edge.

#### Additional possibility that I think is very stupid

Strictly speaking, an [earlier part of the rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MovingAroundOtherCreatures) includes this line:

> Whether a creature is a friend or an enemy, you can't willingly end your move in its space.

A possible interpretation of this rule is that whenever either character in the pit takes a turn, they must do absolutely everything in their power to attempt to leave the pit, regardless of how harmful it might be to them. This makes no sense to me and as DM I would ignore it, but this is certainly a rule that exists and is relevant to your situation. I would rather rule it as "each creature is in half-a-space" making the squeezing rule more applicable and this rule less, but I haven't found a clear basis for that interpretation being more official than the other.

Comment: I always found the RAW rule that a medium creature effectively cannot squeeze a pretty silly oversight. In combat a medium creature cannot willingly walk through a 3ft wide(standard) door...

Comment: The last rule is simply meant as a way to say that, all things being equal, they would prefer to be in their own square at the end of a turn, which makes using miniatures more usable for groups that use them (imagine trying to stack two icons into a single square). Even when grappling, characters still end up in their own square, despite the obvious fact that they would indeed be sharing a square...

Answer (score 2):

As a DM I would rule both creatures were squeezing as they were occupying a space that was too small for them to naturally use during combat. Which entails several penalties as mentioned below.

> Squeezing into a Smaller Space

> A creature can squeeze through a space that is large enough for a creature one size smaller than it. Thus, a Large creature can squeeze through a passage that's only 5 feet wide. While squeezing through a space, a creature must spend 1 extra foot for every foot it moves there, and it has disadvantage on attack rolls and Dexterity saving throws. Attack rolls against the creature have advantage while it's in the smaller space.

Comment: Keep in mind these are partially offsetting if fighting against each other, however both would be vulnerable to someone else attacking.